# Find Layer name by click on features in OpenLayers5

Tags: openlayers

I have two vector layers showed but want to differentiate features show for layer1 and layer2. I have this code:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });
if (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
```

How can I now add another if clause, something like:

```
    if (feature.layer == 'layer1') { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var featureLayer;
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
        featureLayer = layer;
        return feature;
    });

if (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
    if (featureLayer.get('title') == 'layer1') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I try but don't work

Comment: I've updated the answer.  `featureLayer.title` wouldn't work.  It should have been `featureLayer.get('title')` or `featureLayer.get('name')` or whatever property you are using to identify your layers.

Comment: Yesss, thank you a lot! Now work ok. `featureLayer.get('title')` work ok, but `featureLayer.get('name')` not. I search to find if this is the correct property name, but didn't find any useful info.